# How to Design a Cache that Forgets (almost only) on Memory Pressure in Python?

Tags: python, caching

Lets say I have an URL class in Python. The URL class represents an URL and offers a method to download its contents. It also caches that content to speed up subsequent calls.

```
@dataclass(frozen)
class URL:
    url: str
    _cache: Optional[bytes] = None

    def get_content(self) -> bytes:
        if self._cache is None:
            self._cache = requests.get(self.url)
        return self._cache
```

This code worked fine so far. Now I was asked to download huge amounts of URLs here (for sane reasons). To prevent the possibility of misusage, I want to support use cases where every instance of `URL` will be alive until all URLs are downloaded.

Having huge amounts of `URL` alive and cached will lead to memory exhaustion. Now I am wondering how I could design a cache that forgets only when there is memory pressure.

I considered following alternatives:

- **WeakValueDictionaries** will forget as soon as the last strong reference is dropped. This is not helpful here as it leads to either having the current situation or to disabling the cache.
- **LRUCache** requires to decide on the capacity before. However, the cache I would need is helpful only if it caches as many elements as anyhow possible. Whether I cache 100 or 1000 of 100.000 is not important.

**tl;dr:** How could I implement a cache in Python that holds weak references and only drops them seldomly and on memory pressure?

**Updates:**

I have no clear criterions in mind. I expect that others have developed good solutions I just do not know of. In Java I suspect that [SoftReferences](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ref/SoftReference.html) would be an acceptable solution.

MisterMyagi found a good wording:

> Say the URL cache would evict an item if some unrelated, numeric computation needs memory?

I want to keep elements as long as possible but free them when any other code of the same python process would need it.

Maybe a solution would drop instances of URL only by the Garbage Collector. Then I could try to configure the Garbage Collector accordingly. But maybe someone has come up with a more clever idea already, so I can avoid to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: What's your criteria for "memory pressure"? The caching taking up x% of the app memory, or x% of the machine memory, or failure to allocate memory?

Comment: I have not yet a criteria for this. I hope that there is a sane choice implemented by a solution I have not found so far. I expect that any solution would at least prevent MemoryError. Maybe its a good start to prevent that objects are freed when there is no owner besides the cache.

Comment: To "prevent that objects are freed when there is no owner besides the cache" just means swapping a weakref container for a regular one – e.g. replacing ``WeakValueDictionary`` with ``dict``. Which *parts* of building a memory-based cache are you struggling with? Do you know how to build a cache *for any policy* in principle?

Comment: I am confident that I could implement a LRU or LFU cache. Using `dict` would result in disabling the cache behaviour. Trying to catch `MemoryError` in a custom cache based on `dict` is not sufficient as I cannot guarantee that `MemoryError` will occur inside the cache.

Comment: I'm not quite following: What do you mean by "Using ``dict`` would result in disabling the cache behaviour."? Caches with an explicit policy *do* use strong-reference containers, in order to explicitly manage lifetimes. For example, ``functools.lru_cache`` uses a custom ``OrderedDict`` implementation. As for guaranteeing where the error occurs – do you want the cache to free an item if *any* other code needs the memory? Say the URL cache would evict an item if some unrelated, numeric computation needs memory?

Comment: "Say the URL cache would evict an item if some unrelated, numeric computation needs memory?" Exactly.

Comment: So weird that java has memory-sensitive caches but python does not. I hope I am misunderstanding something.

Answer (score 1):

I found a nice solution for the concrete problem I was facing. Unfortunately,
this is not a solution to the concrete question, which is concerned only with a
cache. Thus, I will not accept my answer. However, I hope it will be inspiring
for others.

In my application, there is a storage backend which will call
`url.get_content()`. Using the storage backend will look roughly like this:

```
storage = ConcreteStorageBackend()
list_of_urls = [URL(url_str) for url_str in list_of_url_strings]
for url in list_of_urls:
    storage.add_url(url)
storage.sync()  # will trigger an internal loop that calls get_content() on all URLs.
```

It is easy to see that when `list_of_urls` is huge caching `get_content()`
can cause memory problems. The solution here is, to replace (or manipulate) the
URL objects such that the new URL objects retrieve the data from the storage
backend.

1. Replacing them would be cleaner. The usage could be something like
   `list_of_urls = storage.sync()` where `storage.sync()` returns new URL
   instances.
2. Overwriting `URL.get_content()` with a new function would allow the user
   to be completely ignorant about performance considerations here.

In both cases *caching* would mean to avoid downloading the content again and
instead to obtain it from the storage backend. For this, getting data from the
storage backend has to be faster than to download the content again but I
assume this is the case quite often.

*Caching* with means of a storage backend leads to another cool benefit in many
cases: The OS kernel itself takes care of the cache. I assume that most storage
backends will eventually write to disk, e.g. to a file or to a database. At
least the Linux kernel caches disk IO in free RAM. Thus, as long as your RAM is
sufficiently big you'll get most of the `url.get_content()` at the speed of
RAM. However, the cache does not block other more important memory allocations,
e.g. for *some unrelated, numeric computation* as mentioned in one comment.

Again, I am aware that this is not exactly matching the question above, as it
relies on a storage backend and does not fall back to download data from
internet again. I hope this answer is helpful for others anyways.